# How to preload next background css image on jQuery click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preload

What I am trying to achieve is when clicking on an unordered list item the background changes for a specific div class without it fading out to the white background so it preload the next image and then fades in once loaded.

My HTML code is below:

```
<div class="loadcourse holebg01">
    <div class="coursewrap">
        <div class="courseinfo">
            <h5>Braid’s Walk</h5>
            <p>CONTENT IN HERE</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabnav">
    <ul class="coursenav">
        <li id="1" class="active">1</li>
        <li id="2">2</li>
        <li id="3">3</li>
        <li id="4">4</li>
        <li id="5">5</li>
        <li id="6">6</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.coursenav li').click(function() {
        var holeno = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.coursewrap').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
    $(".coursewrap").fadeOut(400, function () {
        $('.loadcourse').css('background-image', 'url(/uploads/course-images/course' + holeno + '.jpg)');
        $('.coursewrap').fadeIn(400).load('inc/load-course.php?holeno=' + holeno);
        $('.courseinfo').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
});
```

Any help will be great and adjustments to my code and better ways to improve if needed.